# Setting and clearing multiple bits stored as integer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a table that has a column 'userExtraStatus' with type signed integer.

I am storing bits for various user statuses.

to set bits I have a query

```
UPDATE 
    publicUsers 
SET 
    userExtraStatus = userExtraStatus |1024 |2048 |1 
WHERE 
    userID='1'
```

All three bits are set. Column value = **3073** (1024 + 2048 + 1) which is correct as I see it.

If I try to unset any of the bits, for example '1024' and keep the remaining bits as is I am using a query

```
UPDATE 
    publicUsers 
SET 
    userExtraStatus = userExtraStatus |1024 &~ 2048 | 1 
WHERE 
    userID='1'
```

And the result is still **3073**

Expected result: **1025** (which is 3073 - 2048)

Am I missing something with Bitwise operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this.

```
SELECT ( 1024 | 2048 | 1 ) & ~2048
```

or use simple minus.

```
SELECT ( 1024 | 2048 | 1 ) - 2048
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bacec0/25

Example usage with your update query. 
 
Assuming the field userExtraStatus contains `( 1024 |2048 | 1 = 3073 )` already.

```
UPDATE 
    publicUsers 
SET 
    userExtraStatus = (userExtraStatus) & ~2048
WHERE 
    userID='1'
```

**Editted because off comment**

> Is there a way I can mix instructions for Setting and Unsetting bits
>   in one query? For example If I sumbit a form with checkboxes for each
>   bits - I do not want to check if the particular bit is already set - I
>   want it to be set therefore resulting in a query `UPDATE ... SET status
>   = status | bit1 | bit2 &~ bit3`

That's possible but you need to use proper parentheses like so

```
UPDATE ... SET status = ( status | bit1 | bit2 ) & ~bit3
```

Unsetting multiple bits is possible with

```
UPDATE ... SET status = ( status | bit1 | bit2 ) & ~( bit3 | bit4 )
```

That's possible but you need to use proper parentheses like so

Comment: Is there a way I can mix instructions for Setting and Unsetting bits in one query? For example If I sumbit a form with checkboxes for each bits - I do not want to check if the particular bit is already set - I want it to be set therefore resulting in a query UPDATE ... SET status = status | bit1 | bit2 &~ bit3

Comment: @Didzis That's possible but you need to use 
proper parentheses like so `UPDATE ... SET status = ( status | bit1 | bit2 ) & ~bit3 `  Unsetting multiple bits is possible with `UPDATE ... SET status = ( status | bit1 | bit2 ) & ~( bit3 | bit4 )`

Comment: Ah-ha, excellent! Thank you! If you could update your previous answer with these comments I would mark it as accepted.